# Trying to modify an AutoCAD CUI Macro command

Tags: macros, customization, autocad

I am using AutoCAD 2014 LT.

I have bought a library on AutoCAD which lets me insert blocks as slide very easily, through a CUI menu (`ACADLT/Partial Customization/CustomLibrary/Menus`). 
I would like to add a slide file (which a already have).

From what I've been able to find online, I have to modify the macro, but the macro itself is really short:

```
$!=CustomLib-1.image_sub $!=* //Where sub changes depending on which submenu is selected
```

I understand the `$` means its `DIESEL` language, but I do not understand the `!`, or what the image command means. I tried to go edit the `CustomLib-1.CUI` file in WordPad, but it clearly says I should modify it in AutoCAD through the CUI. I also have a CUIX file but I can't seem to open it, either in WordPad or AutoCAD.

I know I'm not missing much, but the last step is where I've been stuck for the past few days.

Comment: To edit the  CUI(x) file you have to open it with  the CUI command in AutoCAD.  On the commandline type "CUI",  a dialog is shown.  Next on the Transfer tab open the file. And try to find the command.

Comment: Also, I think a CUIX file is essentially a ZIP file. I if you rename it you can open it to see what is in it. But as mentioned, Autocad has  CUIX editor.